# Occasional stuttering with "stacked" transitions on `translate()` (v4.0.0-alpha40)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, babeljs

#### Problem: Jerks

I have a D3 **v4.0.0-alpha.40** graph, which periodically (not on every frame):

1. Gets new data point
2. Removes old Data point
3. Reset transition and set `translate(null)`
4. Starts new `transition()` new scrolls across as it get new values.

```
// Animation
function animateOnce(period) {
    // Data: Add new, and remove old
    data.unshift(Math.random());
    data.pop();
    // Do 2 transitions...
    path
      .attr("d", line)
      .transition() /* ...reset */
        .attr("transform", null)
        .duration(0)
      .transition()/* ...scroll across */
        .duration(period)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .attr("transform", `translate(${x(1)})`)
};

// Animation looper
function animate() {
    setTimeout(_=> {
        animateOnce(PERIOD);
    animate();
    },
  PERIOD);
}
```

However the transitions don't seem to execute cleanly - every few seconds there is a *jerk*.

I previously had this problem with **D3 v3**, but I believe I fixed it by adding in the reset transition (step 3 above). Unfortunately I'm not experiences with D3 and I'm not sure how to tackle this.

#### See it

[This jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvz98na9/8/) is an approximation of my graph, and you should be able to see the occasional jerk.

Note: the fiddle uses `setTimeout` while my actual graph is react component, updated with `componentDidUpdate()`.

**Edit 1: Improved using using interrupt**

[Improved jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdpkeebf/3/)

While reading docs (as @Ashitaka suggested) - I found [interrupt()](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections#interrupt). This kills the transition properly and may be the "**v4** way" of achieving *Step 3* above (reset transition).

```
// Animation
function animateOnce(period) {
    // Data: Add new, and remove old
    data.unshift(Math.random());
    data.pop();
    // Do 2 transitions...
    path
      .attr("d", line)
      .interrupt() /* ...reset */
      .attr("transform", null)
      .transition()/* ...scroll across */
        .duration(period)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .attr("transform", `translate(${x(1)})`)
};
```

This has improved the *jerks* (caused I assume by *competing transitions*), by turning them into small *stutters*.

I'd like to get understand where the (I assume 1 frame) stutter is being introduced. So I'll leave this open for now.

Comment: I removed the first transition as i dont think you need that, the (transition,null), removed the ease and it looks better not perfect though . . https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/qvz98na9/10/

Comment: @thatOneGuy The transition actually stops working then (on Chrome at least), it perhaps looks better because its _consistently_ stuttering :P

Comment: It's got something to do with the `setTimeout`.  If you nix that and let the transition itself control the updates, it goes away.  See here: https://jsfiddle.net/qvz98na9/11/

Comment: Just wanted to tell you that just by switching from `https://npmcdn.com/d3@4.0.0-alpha.40/build/d3.min.js` to `https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js` the problem is solved. Must have been some bug in D3v4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mike Bostock's post [Working with Transitions](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/), he writes that:

> For a given element, transitions are exclusive: only one transition
>   can be running on the element at the same time. Starting a new
>   transition on the element stops any transition that is already
>   running.

Now, I detect two problems in the presented code:

1. The path transform reset is being animated (even with `0` duration). This new transition is cancelling the previous transition. This can be fixed by changing:

   ```
   path
     .attr("d", line)
     .transition()
       .attr("transform", null)
       .duration(0)
   ```

   to:

   ```
   path
     .attr("d", line)
     .attr("transform", null)
   ```
2. The `animateOnce` function is being called with the same period as D3's transition and [a transition tick lasts for ~17 ms](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Transitions#starting-transitions). This new transition is cancelling the previous transition as well. This can be fixed by changing:

   ```
   function animate() {
     setTimeout(_=> {
       animateOnce(PERIOD);
       animate();
     },
     PERIOD);
   }
   ```

   to:

   ```
   function animate() {
     setTimeout(_=> {
       animateOnce(PERIOD);
       animate();
     },
     PERIOD + 20);
   }
   ```

   which can be further refactored with [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to:

   ```
   function animate() {
     setInterval(animateOnce, PERIOD + 20, PERIOD);
   }
   ```

These 2 changes should solve the jank issues. Still, updating that line chart every 80 ms will always be taxing on someone's computer or smartphone. I'd advise you to only update it every 200 ms or so.

EDIT: I did some experimenting and noticed that there was still some jank on Firefox. So, a few more points to take into account:

3. Setting the `transform` property to `null` actually creates a new [layer](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/). This can be fixed by changing:

   ```
   .attr("transform", null)
   ```

   to:

   ```
   .attr("transform", "translate(0)")
   ```
4. The transform strings are being recreated every time the `animateOnce` function is called. We can precompute them outside of `animateOnce` and then reuse them. This can be fixed by changing:

   ```
   .attr("transform", "translate(0)")
   .attr("transform", `translate(${x(1)})`)
   ```

   to:

   ```
   // outside the animateOnce function:
   let startStepAttrs = { transform: "translate(0)" },
       endStepAttrs   = { transform: `translate(${x(1)})` };

   // inside the animateOnce function:
   .attr(startStepAttrs)
   .attr(endStepAttrs)
   ```

Comment: This was my first thought as well but doesn't work.  If you remove the zero duration transition you end up with stuttering on every step.  It's that transition that provides for the smoothness...  See here: https://jsfiddle.net/qvz98na9/12/.  You are right though that it's a **stacked** transition problem.

Comment: It does work. You made a mistake and added 20 ms to the `animateOnce` function instead of adding them to the `setTimeout` function.

Comment: Do'h! Sorry!  I rescind my comment and upvote accordingly.

Comment: Ah doesn't really work for me - I still see a stutter I'm afraid, https://jsfiddle.net/tL54quLe/ and https://jsfiddle.net/tL54quLe/1/ RE:setInterval - I actually need to to occur on varying intervals anyway

Comment: This last jsfiddle looks good to me! I've updated my answer with one more possible fix, but honestly I'm not seeing what else we can do. Does this stuttering also occur on Safari or Firefox? Because if it doesn't then it's possible that this is a Macbook Chrome issue.

Comment: I'm not confident of "Here's the key part:" was the key part of my problem in my specific situation. Would you might terribly if I rephrased it to "Keep in mind:"? If I deep dive back into this problem I will put it back if it proves to be so